# Problem recognizing usb device

Tags: usb, udev

There was once a time (yesterday) when I could load this device (a scanning probe microscope controller made by soft db) without problem.  Then Ubuntu crashed.  Now I can no longer load the device.  By load the device I mean udev should make a file in /dev called sranger_mk2_1.  It used to do that whenever I plugged it in, now it doesn't.

When it was behaving properly and I ran udevadm monitor -e, it gave:

```
KERNEL[2544.078497] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=003
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/003/010
DEVNUM=010
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=265
PRODUCT=1612/103/150
SEQNUM=2712
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

KERNEL[2544.078761] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=255/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v1612p0103d0150dc00dsc00dp00icFFisc00ip00in00
PRODUCT=1612/103/150
SEQNUM=2713
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

KERNEL[2544.078931] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/usbmisc/sranger_mk2_1 (usbmisc)
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sranger_mk2_1
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/usbmisc/sranger_mk2_1
MAJOR=180
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=2714
SUBSYSTEM=usbmisc

UDEV  [2544.088140] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=003
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/003/010
DEVNUM=010
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=Signal_Ranger_mk3
ID_MODEL_ENC=Signal\x20Ranger\x20mk3
ID_MODEL_ID=0103
ID_REVISION=0150
ID_SERIAL=Soft-dB_Signal_Ranger_mk3
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
ID_VENDOR=Soft-dB
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Soft-dB
ID_VENDOR_ID=1612
MAJOR=189
MINOR=265
PRODUCT=1612/103/150
SEQNUM=2712
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=2544086838

UDEV  [2545.097132] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
.MM_USBIFNUM=00
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
DRIVER=sranger_mk2
INTERFACE=255/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v1612p0103d0150dc00dsc00dp00icFFisc00ip00in00
PRODUCT=1612/103/150
SEQNUM=2713
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=2544088934

UDEV  [2545.098944] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/usbmisc/sranger_mk2_1 (usbmisc)
.MM_USBIFNUM=00
ACTION=add
DEVNAME=/dev/sranger_mk2_1
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/usbmisc/sranger_mk2_1
MAJOR=180
MINOR=1
SEQNUM=2714
SUBSYSTEM=usbmisc
USEC_INITIALIZED=2545098477
```

I don't entirely understand why it runs three separate things, but I think the important one the one with subsystem=usbmisc, since that is the one that is missing when it stops working.

When it is not behaving properly (i.e. when udev writes nothing to /dev), it gives only this:

```
KERNEL[3837.850624] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=003
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/003/026
DEVNUM=026
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1
DEVTYPE=usb_device
MAJOR=189
MINOR=281
PRODUCT=1612/103/150
SEQNUM=2683
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

KERNEL[3837.851281] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=255/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v1612p0103d0150dc00dsc00dp00icFFisc00ip00in00
PRODUCT=1612/103/150
SEQNUM=2684
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0

UDEV  [3837.856450] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1 (usb)
ACTION=add
BUSNUM=003
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/003/026
DEVNUM=026
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1
DEVTYPE=usb_device
DRIVER=usb
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=Signal_Ranger_mk3
ID_MODEL_ENC=Signal\x20Ranger\x20mk3
ID_MODEL_ID=0103
ID_REVISION=0150
ID_SERIAL=Soft-dB_Signal_Ranger_mk3
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ff0000:
ID_VENDOR=Soft-dB
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Soft-dB
ID_VENDOR_ID=1612
MAJOR=189
MINOR=281
PRODUCT=1612/103/150
SEQNUM=2683
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=3837855936

UDEV  [3838.867971] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0 (usb)
.MM_USBIFNUM=00
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
INTERFACE=255/0/0
MODALIAS=usb:v1612p0103d0150dc00dsc00dp00icFFisc00ip00in00
PRODUCT=1612/103/150
SEQNUM=2684
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=3837861377
```

I am somewhat new to this world and therefore have very little clue as to how to interpret the problem.  The problem has occurred several times before and my solution has just been to go nuclear and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, which works, but I feel there must be a better way.  Any thoughts on what is happening?

EDIT: Just figured it out.  It turns out the module associated with the hardware must have gotten corrupted during the crash so that the kernel was no longer recognizing the board.  I reinstalled the modules and it is now working.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: Does lsblk give any output? Ie does the system see your device?

Comment: @brndn2k lsblk doesn't seem to see it.  That's to say, when I run it while the device is powered on the output is the same as when I run it while the device is powered off.

Answer (score 0):

I've read a little from `man udevadm`. The following may serve your purpose:

```
sudo udevadm trigger -s=usbmisc /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.7/0000:03:00.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/usbmisc/sranger_mk2_1
```

See if functional, if not, continue with:

`sudo udevadm control -R`

-R from the man page:

       `-R, --reload
          Signal systemd-udevd to reload the rules files and other databases like the kernel
           module index. Reloading rules and databases does not apply any changes to already
           existing devices; the new configuration will only be applied to new events.`

I hope this helps.

Comment: The trigger command returns "unable to open the device".  I also tried the reload command and this doesn't make any difference.  It seems like the kernel just isn't mounting it in the right place, or is failing to find the drivers... is something like that possible?